# AutoMapper custom resolver on the child type

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Owner OwnerData {get;set}
}

public class Owner
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}


public class CarProfile : Profile
{
    public CarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Car, Owner>()
          .ForMember(m => m.OwnerData.Name, o=>o.MapFrom(p=>p.Name));
    }
}

Owner ownerData = repository.Get<Owner>(id);
IEnumerable<Car> data = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Car>>(ownerData);
```

> "ClassName": "System.ArgumentException", "Message": "Expression 'm =>
> m.OwnerData.Name' must resolve to top-level member and not any child
> object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the
> child type or the AfterMap option instead.",

How can I map this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using ForMember but setting a child member of Owner.
replace ForMember with ForPath and it should work

```
CreateMap<Car, Owner>()
    .ForPath(m => m.OwnerData.Name, o=>o.MapFrom(p=>p.Name));
```

Comment: If you can paste the updated code here, it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because you are using 2 level in the dest lambda.

With Automapper, you can only map to 1 level. To fix the problem you need to use a single level.

```
CreateMap<Owner, Car>().ForMember(dest => dest.OwnerData,
         input => input.MapFrom(i => new Owner { Name = i.Name }));
```

Comment: with this I'm having "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nObject -> IEnumerable`1\r\nSystem.Object -> System.Collections.Generic

Comment: The reason for this error is that you try to map an object(owner) to a list of cars, and automapper do not know how to do this. Basically you can map your owner to just a car not to an enumerable of cars. Because how you will map a n owner to a list of cars (how many cars your list will have?)

Comment: I want to map list of cars, not a single car, and for every single car in the collection the owner data is the same.

Comment: The idea is the same, how you will now how many cars you will have in your collection